# Mathematicas Map and Join functions used together

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been fiddling with some Mathematica code to join 2 lists but doing some operations on the one list before adding it to the other. So for example I have

```
list={{1, "A"}, {1, "B"}, {1, "C"}, {2, "D"}, {2, "E"}, {2, "F"}};
p = {};
q = {};

ones = Select[list, #[[1]] == 1 &];

p = Join[{#[[2]], "t"}, p] & /@ Reverse[ones];
Table[
  q = Join[{{ones[[m, 2]], "t"}}, q];
  , {m, Length[ones]}];

twos = Select[list, #[[1]] == 2 &];

p = Join[{{#[[2]], "t"}}, p] & /@ Reverse[twos];

Table[
  q = Join[{{twos[[m, 2]], "t"}}, q];
  , {m, Length[twos]}];
```

This yields the following values of p and q respectively:

```
p={{{F, t}, {C, t}, {B, t}, {A, t}}, {{E, t}, {C, t}, {B, t}, {A, t}}, {{D, t}, {C, t}, {B, t}, {A, t}}}
```

and

```
q={{F, t}, {E, t}, {D, t}, {C, t}, {B, t}, {A, t}}
```

From what I can gather, the second time `Join` is used with the `/@`or `Map` function, each list item in p which at the moment is `{{C, t}, {B, t}, {A, t}}` is applied to the `Join` function and is added to a list of results. Is there a way to use `Map` and rather apply the join to the new value of `p` each time, so as to obtain a result exactly the same as the value of `q` but achieved with one line of code.

I tried the same line of code using `PrependTo` instead of `Join` and it works fine, I assume this is because `PrependTo` updates the value of `p` each time the function is called. For example `PrependTo[p, {#[[2]], "t"}] & /@ twos;`

The reason I was trying to do it this was was to determine whether it will be more time efficient to use `Join` rather then `PrependTo`. But ran into this problem before I could get an answer.

Another thing I do not quite understand, is why I need to apply `Reverse[]` to the lists when using `Map` to achieve the same result as running through the list using a loop. Could someone possibly explain why this is the case?! I would have assumed `Map` would run through a list forwards. But this behaviour seems to me as though is traversing the list backwards.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Map does traverse the list as you would expect, in a left right direction. I suspect later elements of your code are introducing reversals.

For instance:

```
Sqrt /@ Select[Range@10, OddQ]
```

gives {1, Sqrt[3], Sqrt[5], Sqrt[7], 3}

If you want to apply some function to the ones from your list and another function to the twos the structure in a functional language might look something like this:

```
ans=Join[f1 /@ Select[myList, #[[1]] == 1 &], f2 /@ Select[myList, #[[1]] == 2 &]]
```

Further from your clarification:

Method 1 to produce q:

```
Reverse /@ Reverse@list /. {2 -> "t", 1 -> "t"}
```

Method 2:

```
Reverse@Join[{Last@#, "t"} & /@ Select[list, #[[1]] == 1 &], {Last@#, "t"} & /@ Select[list, First@# == 2 &]]
```

Comment: What ouput did you actually want by the way ?

Comment: Im wanting my output to be the same as q. So basically im wanting to get the same output using Map on a Join, that im getting from using Table using join.